# Google Play Game Service - Cannot unlock Achievements

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have implemented Google Play Game Service into my game by referring to the [quick start](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) given by Google.

I have added the achievement ids in my 'id.xml' file. My game has around 10 achievements. The code to unlock my achievements is as follows:

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), "achievement_1_0");
```

where 'achievement_1_0' is the string name of one of my achievements.

My issue is that non of my achievements are getting unlocked, even when the conditions are correct. After viewing my log, I got this `E/AchievementAgent(13528): Couldn't find local achievement to update for achievement ID achievement_1_0` from the session filter `com.google.android.gms(Session Filter)`

Any thoughts on what might have gone wrong? or is it a bug ..???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for unlocking an achievement is as follows:

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), "your_achievement_id");
```

Here the achievement id is the id you get while creating achievement in Google Game Services.

That is in Google developer Console->Game Services->Your Application->Achievement

[image]

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks Anu, as you can see I have already added this line of code to my project. Hope you can help me with the log report which I have posted along with my question.

Comment: The id you have provided is wrong it seems. That's why I explained what must be the parameter for the unlock function. You should replace the 'achievement_1_0' with its ID in developer console

Answer (score 1):

@Anu is 100% correct. You are indeed using an incorrect ID for your achievements. However, using the codes from the Game services console is a very bad way to refer to your achievements (and it is very error prone).

The better way to refer to an achievement is to export your achievement IDs by using the `Get resources` link at the bottom of the **Achievements** screen in the **Game services** console. These are then placed inside a xml file in your apps resources. It seems like this is what you are referring to in your question (the `id.xml` file), so you may have already completed this step.

Once the xml file is in place you can then refer to your achievements using the descriptive IDs that were exported from the console. Do that as follows:

```
activity.getBaseContext().getString( R.string.achievement_1_0 );
```

Use your main Activity for `activity` and change the `achievement_1_0` to the achievement's  `name` attribute from the xml file. **NOTE**: `achievement_1_0` must NOT be a string (i.e. not in quotes as in your current code), since it is referring to a string resource.

Always use this method to refer to your achievements - do not hardcode either the strings or the codes from the console as it will make your code much harder to maintain.

Comment: Thank you free3dom for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

Im get this error debugging an app not in release.
I fix the problem adding my account/email as a new tester.

```
Google play console > Game Services > Testing > Add tester
```